# Android Background service before API 21

Tags: android

I'm trying to execute a periodic background timer in Android.

The following code it's executed from a service and works with minSdk=21

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent i, int flags, int startId) {   
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+1000, 60000, alarmIntent);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

And the receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Log.i("TAG", "Tick: "+System.currentTimeMillis()+ " "+new Date());
}
```

But if i try the same with min sdk <21 the timer works until i switch off the screen.

any tip ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [setExact](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) for API>19 and [set](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.AlarmManager.OnAlarmListener,%20android.os.Handler))

for newer versions [setAndAllowWhileIdle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Repeating methods don't provide such features.

Do not forget to use WakefullBroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 0):

One way I've seen it done in older code is to call `startCommand` inside of `onCreate`.  Both methods call `onStartCommand`, but doing it this way seemed to make it "stickier".  I raised a question about the redundant calls a few months back and got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678297/what-can-i-expect-when-oncreate-calls-startservice).  I can't say that this will fix your specific problem, but it may be worth a try.